# In what elements has BEC been achieved?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

I'm seeking to compile a list of all atomic (or otherwise) species with which Bose-Einstein condensation has been experimentally achieved.

So far, I've collected

- photons (Klaers 2010)
- excitons (Dai 2011)
- polaritons (Kasprzak 2006)
- helium (atoms: Santos 2001, molecules: Zwierlein 2003)
- sodium (Davis 1995)
- rubidium (Anderson 1995)
- strontium (Stellmer 2010)
- calcium (Kraft 2009)
- lithium (Bradley 1997)
- cesium (Weber 2003)
- hydrogen (Fried 1998)
- chromium (Griesmaier 2005)
- potassium (Modugno 2001)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Nice collection.

As far as I noticed you are also missing Erbium (10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.210401) and Dysprosium (10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.190401).

Indeed it might also be interesting to include the isotopes and perhaps degenerate Fermi gasses. I once saw a periodic table with the achieved degenerate gasses in a talk, which was quite interesting to look at, but am unfortunately not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice list!

Counting different atoms, the only new one I was able to find is [Ytterbium](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3068) (not sure if the reference is the first). You might also want to count different isotopes, a list is given e.g. [here](http://massey.dur.ac.uk/resources/HopkinsMatterwaveOptics.pdf).

It seems that you have considered nonequilibrium condensation as well. In that case, [magnons](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature05117) should be added to the list. Not sure how well established, but one might want to count in [phonons](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2003.11.063), too.